# Redirect to a Catalog Page Filter by specific Categoy Id

Tags: magento-1.9, category, redirect

i'm a beginner so excuse me in advance!
I've made a custom module for create a nested categories dropdown.

My module solution is differnet from this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23168353/nested-categories-dropdown-in-magento but I've start with this one. It's done with a same logic.

Now I've got a big problem. 
When i post the form i would like to redirect to a catalog page filter by the category id that i passed with post method of my form.

So if I undersand I have to make a function "saveAction" on my IndexController.

but what I have to write in it? How can make a redirect to this specific page?

i've try it but it doesn't Work

```
    public function saveAction()
 {
    $catID = ''.$this->getRequest()->getPost('CatId');
    if(isset($catID)&&($catID!='') )
   {
        $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catID);
        $redirect = $_category->getUrl($_category); 
        $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($redirect);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end i do so:

```
public function filterAction()



{
    //recupero i parametri passati nella chaimata POST
    $ParentID = ''.$this->getRequest()->getPost('ParentId');
    $catID=''.$this->getRequest()->getPost('CatId');
    //verifico i parametri
    if(isset($catID)&&($catID!='') && isset($ParentID)&&($ParentID!='') )
   {
        $redirect = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load( $ParentID)->getUrl();
        $redirect = $redirect . '?cat=' . $catID;
        $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($redirect);

        }
    }
```

In practice from my Post i get the ID of my parent Category (Level 1) and of the last child category  and I create my custom url in this way

```
$redirect = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load( $ParentID)->getUrl();
    $redirect = $redirect . '?cat=' . $catID;
```

It's not seem to be the best solution but for now its work fine and i didn't find a better solution yet.